# How to pass application.properties to dockerfile

Tags: java, docker

How Can I select the correct application properties in dockerfile??

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar"]
```

I have two application properties (application.properties and application-prod.properties) in file jar in the following path:
target\edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\

How can I modify the ENTRYPOINT of Dockerfile in orter to select application-prod.properties?

Comment: You can specify individual Spring properties as environment variables; in turn, you can specify these at deployment time, and without recompiling the jar file.  Would this approach work better for you than trying to specify a Spring profile?

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c","java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod edms-influx-device-fixer-1.2.1.jar "]
```